# Unable to upload images with multer

Tags: node.js, react-native

I'm trying to upload images. It's reaching the backend, but the request body and `req.image` are coming out empty.

I have the submission:

```
const handleSubmit = async () => {
  try {
    const data = createFormData();
    console.log(data); // prints the correct request object

    const response = await axios.post(
      `http://${GATEWAY}:5000/api/uploads/single`,
      JSON.stringify(data)
    );

    alert("Upload success!");
    console.log("response.data", response.data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("err caught --> ", err);
  }
};

const createFormData = () => {
  const data = new FormData();

  data.append("title", title); // coming from
  data.append("body", body); // react hooks state (useState)
  data.append("image", {
    height: image.height,
    width: image.width,
    type: image.type,
    uri:
      Platform.OS === "android" ? image.uri : image.uri.replace("file:/", "")
  });

  return data;
};
```

My endpoint:

```
const express = require("express");
const multer = require("multer");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

express().use(bodyParser.json());

const router = express.Router();

// middleware
const auth = require("../../middleware/auth");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, "./images");
  },
  filename(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, `${file.fieldname}_${Date.now()}_${file.originalname}`);
  }
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

// @route  POST api/uploads/single
// @desc   Upload single image
// @access Private
router.post(
  "/single",
  // upload.array("photo", 3),
  auth,
  upload.single("image"),
  (req, res) => {
    console.log("req", req.body); // {}
    console.log("req", req.image); // undefined

    return res.status(200).json({
      message: "Response from backend"
    });
  }
);

module.exports = router;
```

And my `server.js`

```
 const express = require("express");
 const connectDb = require("./config/db");

 const app = express();

 // connect to db
 connectDb();

 // Define routes (some omitted for brevity)
 app.use("/api/uploads", require("./routes/api/uploads"));

 const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

 app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`));
```

For some reason, in the first snippet, if I do not stringify the `data: FormData` object that is built from `createFormData()`, my backend is never even reached.

I've tried so many things, and I'm not starting to think that maybe my backend isn't setup properly. The line where I'm doing `express().use(bodyParser.json());` exists because I can't do `app.use(bodyParser.json());` (or at least I think), because the app object is in the main `server.js` file. I'm including other API routes in other files.

For example, my `server.js` has these, amongst others:

```
// Define routes
app.use("/api/auth", require("./routes/api/auth"));
app.use("/api/users", require("./routes/api/users"));
app.use("/api/profile", require("./routes/api/profile"));
app.use("/api/uploads", require("./routes/api/uploads"));
```

And I was following [this](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/how-to-upload-images-in-a-react-native-app-4cca03ded855) tutorial to use multer with react-native. A little lost at this point, not sure what I'm doing wrong.

---

Edit:

I'm making the request like this now,

```
  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    }
  };

  const response = await axios.post(
    `http://${GATEWAY}:5000/api/uploads/single`,
    data,
    config
  );
```

But It's failing with a

[image: img]

If I stringify it, it hits the backend but not in the way I need it to:

[image: img2]

---

Edit:

I got it working by specifying the image type, as per the suggestion [here](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1321#issuecomment-518115495)

Comment: To send your app from index file to routes do the following:
app.use("/api/auth", require("./routes/api/auth")(app));

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because you are not setting your content-type to multipart/form-data. Try adding this to your request options:

```
const response = await axios.post(
  `http://${GATEWAY}:5000/api/uploads/single`,
  data,
  headers: {
    `Content-Type`: `multipart/form-data`
  }
);
```

Because of multipart/form-data, do not stringify the data you are sending. Stringifying the data will cause it to only be read as text by the server but is expecting a file to be attached.

Comment: It's telling me `Error: Multipart: Boundary not found`

Comment: When I do `headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }` it *kinda* works, but `req.body.image` isn't what I need, it's `req.image`

Comment: Since you are stringifying the object it isn't being read as the correct content-type, updating my answer with an edit

Comment: I can't reach the backend without stringifying it, though. I get an error, `[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Network request failed]
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/vendor/core/whatwg-fetch.js:504:29 in onerror`

Comment: The only time my backend is reached is if I stringify the data. Once I do that, req.files isn't a thing.

Comment: I just need to figure out why the network is responding with a failure, it's baffling. Why would only stringified data go through

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access the file from req.image and req.body, but as mentioned in the https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer, you can access it from :

```
req.file
```

req.body will hold the text fields only, on the other hand, if you only uploaded a single file you can find it in req.file, but if you uploaded multiple files you will find them in req.files.

Comment: I've made an edit to the OP, I can't reach the backend without stringifying `data`. But once its stringified, neither `req.file` nor `req.files` exist

Comment: Why do you have to send the files stringefied?

Comment: remove "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data", and try without it and don't stringify the data.

Comment: Nope, I got it working another way, updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by specifying the image type as per the suggestion [here](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1321#issuecomment-518115495)

Answer (score 0):

I used the following line to get images:-

```
concole.log(req.files);
```